# Is it a problem to say a city filled with Torah learners is an "Ir Hakodesh"?

Tags: tractate-megillah, yerushalayim-jerusalem

After hearing someone say "___(Yeshiva community) Ir Hakodesh," another Yid corrected him and said, "Yerushalayim is an Ir Hakodesh. ___ is not an Ir Hakodesh. It is an Ir HaTorah."

Is it a problem and/or incorrect to call a Yeshiva community of Torah learners an Ir Hakodesh? (Especially since the [Gemara Megillah (29a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.29a.9?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says the places we learn Torah outside Israel will be "transported" to be part of Eretz Yisroel.)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Holy_Cities#:~:text=The%20Four%20Holy%20Cities%20of,the%20Ottoman%20conquest%20of%20Palestine.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3656661/jewish/Four-Holy-Cities-of-Israel-What-and-Why.htm

Comment: Obviously it was used for other cities as well although those cities had different reasons. The word kodesh means separate from the others.